# Joining two tables with different values in one column

Tags: sql, oracle, join, pivot

I am not an expert in sql.
I have some data like below:

```
select column1,column2,cloumn3 from table1;

----------------------------------------------

sub1  2207   43
sub2  2207   45
sub3  2207   47

select column1,column2,cloumn3,attribute_name,attribute_value from table2;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

sub1  2207   43  ENTITY_ID          VIJAY
sub2  2207   45  ENTITY_ID          SHANKAR
sub2  2207   45  ACTIVATION_DATE    01052018
sub3  2207   47  ENTITY_ID          RISHI
sub3  2207   47  ACTIVATION_DATE    01042018
```

I need an output like :

```
sub1  2207   43   VIJAY       NULL   
sub2  2207   45   SHANKAR     01052018
sub3  2207   47   RISHI       01042018
```

And this seems to be tough one for me. Could anybody help me to find the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `PIVOT` operator - and only `table2` is absolutely necessary:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, ..., attribute_name, attribute_value
      FROM table2
) PIVOT (
    MAX(attribute_value)
    FOR attribute_name IN ('ENTITY_ID' AS entity_id, 'ACTIVATION_DATE' AS activation_date)
)
 ORDER BY column1;
```

[**See working SQL Fiddle here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca33b/2).

Note that the `MAX()` within the `PIVOT` is only there because `PIVOT` expects an aggregate function. `MIN()` will work just as well (there is only one value).

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Just saw your comment about many other columns in `table1` that you need. In that case you'll want something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3, ..., t2.attribute_name, t2.attribute_value
      FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
       AND t1.column2 = t2.column2
       AND t1.column3 = t2.column3
) PIVOT (
    MAX(attribute_value)
    FOR attribute_name IN ('ENTITY_ID' AS entity_id, 'ACTIVATION_DATE' AS activation_date)
)
 ORDER BY column1;
```

**EDIT #2:** If you need to convert `ACTIVATION_DATE` to an actual date, you can do something like the following:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ..., entity_id
     , TO_DATE(activation_date, 'ddmmyyyy') AS activation_date
  FROM (
    SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3, ..., t2.attribute_name, t2.attribute_value
      FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
       AND t1.column2 = t2.column2
       AND t1.column3 = t2.column3
) PIVOT (
    MAX(attribute_value)
    FOR attribute_name IN ('ENTITY_ID' AS entity_id, 'ACTIVATION_DATE' AS activation_date)
)
 ORDER BY column1;
```

But if you're storing dates as strings that conversion may not be 100% safe.

Comment: Thanks David.This is working. I needed something with PIVOT and you nailed it.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

How about two joins?

```
select t1.*, t2e.attribute_value, t2d.attribute_value
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2e
     on t1.col1 = t22.col1 and t1.col2 = t2e.col2 and t1.col3 = t2e.col3 and
        t2e.attribute_name = 'ENTITY_ID' left join
     table2 t2d
     on t1.col1 = t22.col1 and t1.col2 = t2e.col2 and t1.col3 = t2e.col3 and
        t2e.attribute_name = 'ACTIVATION_DATE';
```

Or, because you don't seem to need anything from `table1`, you can use `group by`:

```
select col1, col2, col3,
       max(case when attribute_name = 'ENTITY_ID' then attribute_value end),
       max(case when attribute_name = 'ACTIVATION_DATE' then attribute_value end)
from table2
group by col1, col2, col3;
```

Comment: There are many other columns in table1 which I need So cannot use the second solution.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to do something like this with sub-queries:

```
select column1,column2,cloumn3
 , (
   select attribute_value
   from table2 b
   where attribute_name = 'ENTITY_ID'
     and a.column1 = b.column1
     and a.column2 = b.column2
     and a.column3 = b.column3
 )
 , (
   select attribute_value
   from table2 b
   where attribute_name = 'ACTIVATION_DATE'
     and a.column1 = b.column1
     and a.column2 = b.column2
     and a.column3 = b.column3
 )
from table1 a;
```

Other option, more pretty and maybe with better performance, depending on the DB engine would be to use a pivot of the second table and then join it with the first. But I will let it be you to investigate on it if your interested.

Comment: Good one, But I feel there might be performance issue with this

Comment: The only way to make sure regarding performance is to try it, but you can browse more about the pivot option in oracle in this link: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php

Comment: Thanks for the reference.